# Using make to compile several files of the same type which are under different subdirectories?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make, osdev

I just started learning make today. I have several assembly files that I want to compile and then join into a single file. For now I have two files in my tree but the makefile code should be able to handle more. So here is what the files look like.

`Src/Boot/MBR.asm`

`Src/Boot/SecondStage/Bootloader.asm`

I want to compile each of these files into the `Bin/` directory that the makefile is located in, where the files should end up like this

`Bin/MBR.bin`

`Bin/Bootloader.bin`

then I will concentrate these two files into one single file `os-image.img`

So far I came up with the following

```
AS := nasm
ASFLAGS_BIN := -fbin

SRCDIR := Src
BINDIR := Bin

BOOTASM = $(shell find $(SRCDIR) -name '*.asm')
BOOTBIN = $(addprefix $(BINDIR)/, $(addsuffix .bin, $(basename $(notdir $(BOOTASM)))))


build: clean compile 
    cat $(BOOTBIN) > Bin/os-image.img

compile: $(BOOTBIN)

$(BOOTBIN) : $(BOOTASM)
    $(AS) $(ASFLAGS_BIN) $< -o $@

clean:
    rm -rf $(BINDIR)/%.bin
```

The output when I type `make` to shell is the following

```
rm -rf Bin/%.bin
nasm -fbin Src/Boot/second/Bootloader.asm -o Bin/Bootloader.bin
nasm -fbin Src/Boot/second/Bootloader.asm -o Bin/MBR.bin
cat Bin/Bootloader.bin Bin/MBR.bin > Bin/os-image.img
```

The expected output is:

```
rm -rf Bin/%.bin
nasm -fbin Src/Boot/second/Bootloader.asm -o Bin/Bootloader.bin
nasm -fbin Src/Boot/second/MBR.asm -o Bin/MBR.bin
cat Bin/Bootloader.bin Bin/MBR.bin > Bin/os-image.img
```

Obviously the problem is in here

```
$(BOOTBIN) : $(BOOTASM)
    $(AS) $(ASFLAGS_BIN) $< -o $@
```

However I couldn't understand how I should be able to achieve what I want since I am pretty inexperienced at this.

So the question is:

How should I get each prerequisite that corresponds to the related target? or something similar to that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `rm -rf $(BINDIR)/%.bin` should probably be: `rm -rf $(BINDIR)/*.bin`

Comment: You can simplify a bit `$(addprefix $(BINDIR)/, $(addsuffix .bin, $(basename $(notdir $(BOOTASM)))))` with `$(patsubst %.asm,$(BINDIR)/%.bin,$(notdir $(BOOTASM)))`

Comment: `$(BOOTBIN) : $(BOOTASM)` means that every `.bin` depends on all `.asm`. Probably not what you want. See pattern rules and static pattern rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with `VPATH` --

```
BOOTASM = $(shell find $(SRCDIR) -name '*.asm')
BOOTBIN = $(addprefix $(BINDIR)/, $(addsuffix .bin, $(basename $(notdir $(BOOTASM)))))
VPATH=$(sort $(dir $(BOOTASM))

$(BOOTBIN) : %.bin : %.asm
    $(AS) $(ASFLAGS_BIN) $< -o $@
```

But, read the [third rule of makefiles](http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/rules-of-makefiles/#rule3) before you got to far down the vpath road...

Another thing you should be aware of -- for

```
build: clean compile 
    cat $(BOOTBIN) > Bin/os-image.img
```

Then `clean` is not guaranteed to run before `compile` (and in fact, on a parallel system they might both try to run at the same time...).   Obviously this would not be what you want.   Either make compile depend on clean (but then it will clean every time you try to compile), or create a seperate `clean_then_compile : clean` target, which runs the compile command on its own.

Comment: I I would like it to clean every time I compile so I will probably make compile depend on clean. I have yet to test vpath but I will mark answer correct the moment I do (which will take long time since it is midnight here), also, I don't understand the third rule, could you elaborate? Also as a side question, I want to make sure that I cat the files in a specific order, MBR.bin first Bootloader.bin second. How could I do that? It seems impossible without typing out file names manually but maybe I thought I could cat them

Comment: In the order I compiled them. Sorry for the seperated comment

Comment: The third rule is that you should use VPATH to find sources, not targets.   There's a bunch of articles on the web that discuss it (in fact, the link I sent you has an internal link that has a good explanation).   Thought I would bring it to your attention.

Comment: As far as cat order goes, you would have to specify the order somehow -- if it's alphabetical, you can use `$(sort $(BOOTBIN))` for example, but realistically, you would have to manually do a list.

Comment: The `clean` _is_ guaranteed to run before the `compile` _unless_ you invoke parallel builds (add `-j` to the make command line).  However, if you want to clean everything every time why even bother to use make?  Just write a simple shell script that runs all your compile commands in whatever order you want them.  There's no point in using make if you just want to run the exact same commands over again every time.

Comment: I just tried copying and pasting the code and test it however it did not work, make said ```make: *** No rule to make target `Bin/Bootloader.asm', needed by `Bin/Bootloader.bin'.  Stop.```

Comment: Well I solved the problem bu removing the ```addprefix``` from ```BOOTBIN``` and adding it manually on compile.

Comment: @MadScientist -- perhaps the order is defined in this context, but if you have `targ1: dep1 dep2` followed by `targ2: dep2 dep1`, and you have `all: targ2 targ1`, then `dep2` will be built before `dep1`.   I just think relying on dependency ordering in this way is a bad practice in general.

Comment: Yes, I agree, but `dep2` will _always_ be considered before `dep1`.  It won't _sometimes_ be considered before `dep1` and sometimes after `dep1`.  Of course I do agree that as a best practice in a makefile you should always explicitly define dependencies and relying on the order of peer prerequisites is a bad idea.  Nevertheless, it's not accurate to say that the order in which make considers targets is non-deterministic: the order is the same every time you run make.